# Como transformar esse código para ele validar múltiplos arquivos?

Tags: php, upload, revisão-de-código

O código abaixo encontrado na [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.multiple.php), permite fazer upload de arquivos, só que ele somente permite um arquivo por *upload*. Como transformar esse código para ele validar múltiplos arquivos?

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

try {

    // Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
    // If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
    if (
        !isset($_FILES['upfile']['error']) ||
        is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error'])
    ) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
    }

    // Check $_FILES['upfile']['error'] value.
    switch ($_FILES['upfile']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
    }

    // You should also check filesize here. 
    if ($_FILES['upfile']['size'] > 1000000) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
    }

    // DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['upfile']['mime'] VALUE !!
    // Check MIME Type by yourself.
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
        array(
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
        ),
        true
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
    }

    // You should name it uniquely.
    // DO NOT USE $_FILES['upfile']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
    // On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'],
        sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s',
            sha1_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
            $ext
        )
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
    }

    echo 'File is uploaded successfully.';

} catch (RuntimeException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Primeiramente você tem que se certificar que os campos `FILE` do formulário sejam "Array":

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Envie esses arquivos:<br />
  <input name="upfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="upfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar arquivos" />
</form>
```

Quando o formulário acima é submetido, as arrays `$_FILES['upfile']`, `$_FILES['upfile']['name']`, e `$_FILES['upfile']['size']` serão colocados em um array `$_FILES`:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo.txt
            [1] => bar.txt
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => text/plain
            [1] => text/plain
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /tmp/phpYzdqkD
            [1] => /tmp/phpeEwEWG
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 456
        )
)
```

no código você terá que colocar um `for` para percorrer todo ele e fazer os respectivos uploads:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['upfile']['name']); $i++){

try {

    // Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
    // If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
    if (
        !isset($_FILES['upfile']['error'][$i]) ||
        is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error'][$i])
    ) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
    }

    // Check $_FILES['upfile']['error'] value.
    switch ($_FILES['upfile']['error'][$i]) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
    }

    // You should also check filesize here. 
    if ($_FILES['upfile']['size'][$i] > 1000000) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
    }

    // DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['upfile']['mime'][$i] VALUE !!
    // Check MIME Type by yourself.
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'][$i]),
        array(
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
        ),
        true
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
    }

    // You should name it uniquely.
    // DO NOT USE $_FILES['upfile']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
    // On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'][$i],
        sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s',
            sha1_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'][$i]),
            $ext
        )
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
    }

    echo 'File is uploaded successfully.';

} catch (RuntimeException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}

}

?>
```

Comment: 1º: Tem um erro na linha 5, falta o ; na condição. 2°: Você passa o upload por $_POST, enquanto deveria passar por $_FILES.

Comment: Arrumado vlw....

Comment: Não arrumou não. É $_FILE**S**. Faltou o **S**.

Comment: Ninguém aqui foi estúpido, você disse que arrumou, enquanto na verdade ainda estava errado, estava faltando o **S**. Ou está 100% certo, ou está errado.

Comment: Guilherme, o Stormwind apenas fez um apontamento, ele esta é lhe ajudando, seja respeitoso, siga nosso modelo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice, em nenhum momento o Storwind o ofendeu ou depreciou algo, ele apenas apontou vossas falhas que podem ser corrigidas para assim melhorar a resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento educação cabe aqui e em todo lugar o apontamento inicial foi respeitoso e o tratei bem, mas por que esqueci um S o cara vir falar que não arrumei... haaa pf.... não custava nada ser educado, assim como ele eu erro também.

Comment: Não vi em nenhum momento falta de edução, ele apenas deu enfase para lhe ajudar a corrigir problemas em seu código, cabe a você não levar pro lado pessoa e entender como uma critica construtiva, não há necessidade de exageros.

Comment: @GuilhermeBiancardi, o apontamento do Stormwind foi certo e coerente. Por mais que, humanamente, o erro fora de 1 caracter em 1000 (portanto erro de 0.1%), o compilador/interpretador do código não gerará o resultado previsto. Imagina que você escreveu uma classe inteira em Java e esqueceu um `;`: o seu código estará errado. Ou então no Python você mistura no mesmo bloco de identação 2 espaços e 3 espaços. A implementação está errada.